# How to check AJAX call is completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page where I have to bind the few controls via ajax call.
Country drop down, state drop down on the basis of selected country, city drop down on the basis of selected city. Nested data binding is working fine.

But If I have some initial values of country, state, city & I have to set the selected values, then this is not working. I am calling a function to set initial values like below:

```
function bindandsetvalues(_country, _state, _city){

  // function to bind countries via ajax call. ajax logic is inside this function
  bindcountries();

  if($("#country").length > 0){
    // set selected country
    $("#country").val(_country);

    // function to bind states via ajax call. ajax logic is inside this function
    bindstates(_country);

    if($("#state").length > 0){
      // set selected state
      $("#state").val(_state);
    }
  }
}
```

But only country drop down is populated. Neither initial value of country sets nor state drop down binds.

I have also found the reason.
After calling bindcountries() function, control goes to the bindcountries() function. But there is a asynchronous ajax call inside bindcountries() function, so after calling the ajax call, control gets back to the caller function without waiting for the completion of ajax call where I called

$("#country").val(_country);

But because ajax async call is still in progress & country drop down will be bind & render after completing the ajax call.

So, Neither initial value of country sets nor state drop down binds.
So, My question is: Is there any way to check or wait for the completion of AJAX async call, so that I will check the existence of rendered control ($("#state").length > 0) after that that time/completing ajax call.

I know there is are .done, .fail & .always methods of jquery ajax where I can handle post ajax call logic. But in my above case, I can't use those methods. & there are more than eight this type of nested controls which I have to set.

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: maybe add a alert at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can use    .done()

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  //Write your code here
});
```

Comment: i used above function to fill my dropdown box but when i have more than 2000 rows in database table then its take too much time while page get loading.. and i put $.ajax() function inside document.ready function.  so how to make this process quick any idea??

Comment: sorry i dont have idea on that

Comment: thanks PSR, but as I already mentioned that I can only write the logic to bind & render the country dropdown in .done function. After rendering the country dropdown, I have to set country selected value(ok, I can do it in .done) & then on the basis of country selected value, AJAX call for state dropdown will be initialed. & there are several other information which I have to set only & only if state/city/some other fields rendered. If some field is not rendered/bound due to non availability of data, then further AJAX call will be stopped & we will not set the values of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either **.done** or **.success** methods like

```
$.ajax({
  url  : my_url,
  data : data,
}).done(function() {
   alert('Ajax completed');
});
```

Using **success**

```
$.ajax({
  url  : my_url,
  data : data,
  success : function(){
      alert('Successfully completed ajax');
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there any other way to find out that an AJAX is completed or not. Because I can not do write that code inside .done/.fail/.always function. Because all dropdown also have their "change" event which will fire accordingly & will bind the next child element. But Initially, I have to set some initial values, so I have to fire/ or bind all child controls manually by automating the process.

Comment: yah if you go with 'success' if the ajax is SUCCESSFULLY completed then it will  fire the relative function

Answer (score 0):

You can also check like this

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "url",
   statusCode: { 
          200: function() {
          alert("Ajax call successfully completed");
       }

  });
```

Comment: Is there any other way to find out that an AJAX is completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this like:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            data: request,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function(data){
            //it will be called if everything its ok                    
            },
            error:  function (data) {
              //it will be called if there is something bad in your server                   
            }
        });
```

where "data" has your request for a method and the parameters.

I hope this can help you.

Juanitos

Comment: thanks Juanita, but I have no problem with AJAX call or .done/.fail/.always function. Is there any other way to find out that an AJAX is completed or not. because on the basis of this, I have to do some other processing which I can not do inside .done/.fail/.always function, E.g.: user has saved his profile & go to edit section. Now I have to bind the saved information. here my above process will work. when user comes for registration, we will not pre populate the data (country, state, city etc.). They will fire their "change" event independently & there is no need of nested AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function FillState() {
        var countryId = $('#CountryId').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Student/FillState',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { countryId: countryId },
            success: function (states) {
                $("#StateId").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                    $("#StateId").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(state.Id).html(state.Name));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>




public ActionResult FillState(int countryId = 0)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var states = db.States.Where(x => x.CountryId == countryId).ToList();
            return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }


 ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.States.Where(x => x.CountryId == studentDetail.CountryId), "Id", "Name", studentDetail.StateId);


ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.States.Where(x => x.CountryId == 0), "Id", "Name");
```